# How to open/write/read port in REBOL3?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, rebol2

I have this code in REBOL2:

```
port: open/direct tcp://localhost:8080
insert port request
result: copy port
close port
```

**What would be equivalent in REBOL3?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

REBOL3 networking is async by default, so the code in REBOL3 must look like:

```
client: open tcp://localhost:8080
client/awake: func [event /local port] [
    port: event/port
    switch event/type [
        lookup  [open port]
        connect [write port to-binary request]
        read [
           result: to-string port/data
           close port
           return true
        ]
        wrote [read event/port]
    ]
    false
]
wait [client 30] ;the number is a timeout in seconds
close client
```

Based on: http://www.rebol.net/wiki/TCP_Port_Examples

EDIT: above link does not exists anymore, but here is it transferred to GitHub's wiki: https://github.com/revault/rebol-wiki/wiki/TCP-Port-Examples